# Generating SSRS report in different location passed on the parameter passed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report which accepts a parameter (Country_Name).

This is a weekly report and needs to be generated automatically by triggering the SQL agent job. So, I have created a data driven subscription for this report and created a SSIS package to generate the report from SQL agent job.

**Now the problem is** : Since it is a automated report, there is no interface to pass the parameter to report. So, I have created a table to hold the list of parameters to be passed and the path to place the generated report.

Table will have 2 columns (**Country_Name** & **Report_Path**) and hold values like  **(India \AB123C\India) (China,\ABC\China)** etc.

Depending on the parameter passed, location of the report will change. So, I used looping in data driven subscription query to get the parameter and path. Though there are multiple parameters and path for that respective parameter are returned by the query, it is picking only the first result set and generates report only for the first parameter and its specified location.

I unable to find out the solution for this. Please find the below query I have used for your reference. It would be great if I can get a solution for this.

```
 DECLARE @MinCount INT = 1 
    DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @RecordCount INT
    DECLARE @CurrentDate VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @CountryList Table (ID INT Identity(1,1),Country_Name Varchar(100),Report_path Varchar(max))
    SET @RecordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Country_List)
    WHILE (@MinCOunt < = @RecordCount)
    BEGIN
    SET @Country = (Select Country_name from Country_List WHere ID = @MinCOunt)
    SET @Path = (Select Report_Path from Country_List WHere ID = @MinCOunt)
    SET @CurrentDate = ( SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126) as currentSysDate)
    Delete from  @CountryList
    insert into @CountryList (Country_Name,Report_path) Values (@Country,@Path)
    select 'Country_Details ' +
    @CurrentDate as filename
    ,'Excel' as RenderFormat
    , (select Name from Master where
    Reference_Name = 'USER_NAME'
    ) as sqlUserId  
    ,( select Value from Master where
    Reference_Name = 'PASSWORD'
) as sqlPwd  , (Select Country_Name from @CountryList) AS Issue_Country,
(Select Report_path from @CountryList) AS filePath_cfonereports
SET @MinCOunt = @MinCOunt + 1
END
```

Comment: It's slightly unclear based on your question what the actual problem is. The code you have attached seems to have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: The above code is used in data driven subscription I have created for the report. Based on the values returned by the select statement in above code, the values such as filename, Path, RenderFormat, Reporting server credentials and parameter will be set in subscription to generate the report.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.  What do you mean by "location of the report"?   What are you using to create your subscriptions?

Comment: Location of the report is the path (shared drive) where the report need to be generated. Apologies, I didn't get what you meant by your second question. If it is version of SDT you are asking, it is SQL server Data tools 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue now by using a different approach rather than using looping in subscription code. I created a reference table to store to the list of parameters as well as the corresponding path. Since this report is called from a SSIS package, I have used a variable to get the list of parameters from the reference table and a foreach loop container with  Execute SQL task to pass one parameter from variable at a time and invoke the subscription. So that the report will be generated for that parameter passed and in the path specified. This foreach loop container will loop n times based on the count of parameters in the variable